# Preferred method of working with logical objects

Tags: android, json, performance, object, storage

I'm having an array of objects represented as JSON string that will be coming from an API server. Let's suppose we have some Movie Categories and actual Movies that belong to each category:

```
[
{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Action",
    "movies": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "Movie 1",
            "description": "Movie 1 Description",
            "other": "Other..."
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "Movie 2",
            "description": "Movie 2 Description",
            "other": "Other..."
        }
    ]
},
{
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Drama",
    "movies": [
        {
            "id": "3",
            "name": "Movie 3",
            "description": "Movie 3 Description",
            "other": "Other..."
        },
        {
            "id": "4",
            "name": "Movie 4",
            "description": "Movie 4 Description",
            "other": "Other..."
        }
    ]
}
]
```

The users of my android app will need to be able to browse through categories/movies.
Which of the following scenarios is better regarding the performance of the code and optimal memory usage?
Assume that there will be many channels and categories.
 1. Parse the JSON string once, create ArrayLists of Category and Movie objects for each category that I will later use them for populating lists.
 2. Create a Parser with few methods like get_total_channels, get_channel, get_category that will always parse the contents of the JSON string to return me the appropriate data to populate the lists.
 3. Any other suggestion?

Comment: Why not use some JsonParser to make your work easier? Take a look at this. http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/257-how-to-parse-json-in-java/

Comment: For the JSON parsing for sure i will use the Android's JsonReader . My doubt is how to prepare the parsed data for further usage, e.g. creating views. Creating an object out of every movie could grow the heap till the clouds.